# How to run Python function if I click HTML button in Bottle framework

Tags: python, html, bottle

This is my HTML code for a button:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location='admin_finalpage.html'" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>&nbsp;Ambulance 1
    </button>
</td>
```

I want to run a Python file or function that calculates the exact time of arrival. If I click on this, that redirects to `admin_finalpage` and shows time on page.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I already have python code that is running but I am not able to connect this with HTML button. I mean when I click on this button that should display my result on target window page.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Already having a running python module that knows how to compute some result is fine but at this point mostly irrelevant - what you ask here is still "how to do backend web programming with Python", and the answer is still the same.